# AWS EBS vs EFS with a Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ebs, amazon-efs

I've a lambda function which processes large video files (greater than 512 mbs). The files are to be downloaded from an s3 bucket, processed using ffmpeg and then uploaded back to another s3 bucket. Currently, I'm using the `/tmp/` directory by lambda but it has a limit of 512 mbs.

I've read somewhere that you can use EFS with lambda for this purpose but I think EBS could be used as well but I've not found anyone using that. Is there any particular reason that why EFS could be preferred over EBS in this scenario or with lambda functions in general?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use EBS volumes with lambda. They are used with EC2 instances only. For the lambda you can use EFS only.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda now supports 10GB of ephemeral storage, up from the previous limit of 512 mb. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/

Comment: is that EBS or EFS?

Comment: It is neither EBS nor EFS, it is lambda's own stroage called ephemeral storage. You don't need to set any additional config for it. You just need to specify the size of it. By default its 512 mb.